# Transformation law for spinor functions multiplication

Tags: group-representations, spinors, lorentz-symmetry

Let's have Dirac spinor $\Psi (x)$, which formally corresponds to
$$
\left( 0, \frac{1}{2} \right) \oplus \left( \frac{1}{2}, 0 \right)
$$
representation of the Lorentz group.

What representation is true for $\Psi (x) \Psi^{+}(x')$? I expect something like 
$$
\left[\left(\frac{1}{2}, 0 \right) \oplus \left( 0, \frac{1}{2} \right)\right]\otimes \left[\left( 0, \frac{1}{2} \right) \oplus \left( \frac{1}{2},  0\right)\right] = 
$$
$$
=\left(\frac{1}{2}, 0 \right) \otimes \left(\frac{1}{2}, 0 \right) \oplus \left(\frac{1}{2}, 0 \right) \otimes \left( 0 , \frac{1}{2}\right) \oplus \left( 0, \frac{1}{2} \right) \otimes \left(0, \frac{1}{2} \right) = 
$$
$$
\tag 1 =\left[\left( 0, 0\right)\oplus (1, 0) \right]\oplus \left( \frac{1}{2} , \frac{1}{2}\right) \oplus \left[\left( 0, 0\right)\oplus (0, 1) \right], 
$$
but I'm not sure.

Also I know that 
$$
\tag 2 [\Psi (x), \Psi^{+}(y)]_{+} = i\left( i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} + m\right)\gamma_{0}D_{m}(x - y),
$$ 
where $D_{m}(x - y)$ is a lorentz scalar function, so formally $(2)$ doesn't coinside with $(1)$. How to 
compare it with $(1)$?